# Neo4j delete graph out of memory

Tags: memory, graph, neo4j, bigdata

I'm using neo4j on a linux machine 16G memory 
and I'm trying to delete all the graph .
it has 11353056 relationship vs 19900 nodes.
when I run `Match (n) detach delete n`  after loading for a while I get thee out of memory error .

how can I delete the graph ?
should I proceed by deleting the relationships and then delete the nodes to prevent that problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Do like this to remove records with a limitation:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN count(*);
```

If you want to remove everything like property keys, stop neo4j service and remove everything from `data/graph.db`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use Cypher to delete all the graph you can I stop Neo4j and delete the `data/graph.db` folder. After it restart Neo4j.

Another suggestion is to run your deletion query with a limit repeating it until no more records exists.

For example:

```
Match (n) detach delete n limit 5000
```

Comment: as I'm doing a performance comparaison , deleting the graph.db is not the best thing to do .  so you say it is better to delete portion til finishing , than to delete relations and then the nodes ?

Comment: I believe so. Because depending the quantity of relationships of your graph you can get an out of memory deleting only these relationships. Right?

Comment: Yes the graph has for about  11M relationship

Answer (score 0):

Install the APOC plugin and use this APOC command; it will do the delete in batches of whatever you set `batchSize` to.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (n) RETURN n', 'DETACH DELETE n', {batchSize:1000})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the graph on multiple steps by using LIMIT

ex

```
MATCH (n) with n limit 100 DETACH DELETE n
```

Comment: This answer is no better than the existing answers